# Install version of the windows phone 8 application

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8-emulator

I have created a windows Phone application, and how do I give this application to the client, Do I give him my project folder i.e `Getcontacts`? and also client wants to install this application to emulator because in the client machine only emulator is installed.

Is there any way to create the install file of the application that I give to the client and client will easily install into the emulator. Kindly suggest me on these queries..

Waiting for your reply.

Thanks.

Comment: I think the only way is to upload to store. **EDIT** There several stages for the store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the client has the emulator installed, he can deploy a XAP to it using 'Application Deployment' (open the start menu and type Application Deployment). You can select the target (one of the emulators) and then choose the XAP file.

On your end, set the build configuration to Release and build the solution. Then navigate to the project folder/Bin/Release and that's where you will find the .xap that you need to send to your client.

Here's an MSDN article for the Application Deployment tool: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402565(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402565%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_tool)

Answer (score 0):

To test the app your client need to be a registered developer(He need to create developer account on Microsoft developer.

To Access Application Deployment tool your client needs to **install Windows Phone SKD** 
then launch Application Deployment tool from installed SDK folder
*C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Tools\XAP Deployment\XapDeploy.exe*

OR launch it from start menu by typing Application Deployment.

[image]

Now he just need to give the path of the xap file(debug or release version) and select the desired testing target.

P:S. you can also deploy the app on app store and set publish version to beta for testing the app at any device without having developer account and installing windows phone SDK.